# Excel - How to check if and in how many rows a certain value/string is present in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a list A of strings and I want to see if and if yes in how many rows each string is represented in range B. My data looks something like this:

List A:

aaa

bbb

ccc

```
Range B:

1 aaa --- ---

2 bbb ccc bbb

3 aaa --- ---
```

My desired result would be that in list A for "aaa" it would tell me 2, for "bbb" 1 and for "ccc" 1. Have been trying to do this with the below array formula but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(Range B,List A($A1)>0,1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your lists of strings are in 1 cell per row - you can use an array formula.

We'll say List A is in `A1:A3` and Range B is in `B1:B3`. To count for each one in list A you can use -

```
=COUNT(IF(FIND(A1,$B$1:$B$3)>0,1,0))
```

But this is an array formula, so when you type it you finish by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Entr</kbd> and you'll see curly brackets `{}`.

[image]

---

If Range B is in multiple cells you can just use something like -

```
=COUNTIF($B$6:$D$8,A1)
```

---

There may be another way with formulas, but I can't think of it. You can create a helper column for what you're trying to find using

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1,$B6:$D6)),0,1)
```

Drag it down the rows, then sum that column. But that's a lot of helper columns if you want to count it for each value..

---

If you're open to VBA, a UDF similar to this would work -

```vb
Public Function countrow(rng As Range, str As String) As Integer
Dim a As Integer
a = 0
    For Each Row In rng
        For Each c In Row
            If InStr(1, str, c) Then
                a = a + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    countrow = a
End Function
```

like -

```
=countrow(A6:C9,A1)
```

Comment: Yes, Range B consists of multiple columns. And what I want to know is not the total number of occurrences of a certain value/string (which is what a simple countif formula would give me), but in how many rows that value/string occurs.

Comment: @FBert see my edit, though these solutions may not be ideal for you